# Android Vector image is becoming pixelated after scaling/zooming

Tags: android, svg, vector, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector xml (derived from an SVG) that I'm drawing via an ImageView on a FrameLayout, zoomed in. It's noticeably pixelated, even though the source is a vector. I've tried playing with the scaleType attribute, and the properties of the vector, and nothing seems to address the issue.

The layout is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#333333"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_test"
        android:layout_width="4000dp"
        android:layout_height="4000dp"
        android:translationX="-500dp"
        android:translationY="-500dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_simple"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The xml is:

```
<vector android:height="4383dp" android:viewportHeight="4383.2114"
    android:viewportWidth="4880.7114" android:width="4881dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="1" android:fillColor="#333f61"
        android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M0,0h4880.71v4383.21h-4880.71z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fdb76a"
        android:pathData="m1624.15,238.74c7.01,-7.01 4.67,-16.36 -4.09,-23.38 -8.77,-7.01 -23.96,-10.52 -30.97,-18.7 -7.01,-7.6 -4.67,-19.29 -12.86,-29.22 -7.6,-9.35 -25.13,-17.53 -30.97,-25.13 -5.84,-7.6 0,-15.78 -1.17,-23.38 -0.58,-7.6 -8.77,-15.78 -18.11,-18.7 -9.93,-2.92 -21.62,-0.58 -28.63,2.34 -6.43,2.92 -8.77,6.43 -14.61,11.69 -5.84,4.68 -15.19,10.52 -20.45,14.61 -4.67,3.51 -4.67,5.84 -7.6,8.77 -2.92,2.92 -8.77,6.43 -12.86,8.77 -3.51,1.75 -5.84,1.75 -8.77,8.77 -2.92,6.43 -6.43,20.45 -11.69,29.81 -4.67,9.94 -10.52,15.78 -11.69,24.55 -0.58,8.77 2.92,20.45 5.26,27.47 1.75,6.43 1.75,8.77 2.92,12.27 0.58,4.09 2.92,9.94 6.43,16.95 4.09,6.43 9.93,14.61 15.78,20.45 5.84,5.84 11.69,9.35 12.86,18.12 0.58,8.77 -2.92,22.79 3.51,30.39 7.01,7.6 24.54,9.94 33.31,11.69 8.77,1.75 8.77,4.09 9.93,5.84 0.58,1.75 2.92,4.09 7.6,4.68 4.67,1.17 12.86,1.17 21.62,-1.75 8.77,-2.92 18.11,-8.77 14.61,-17.53 -4.09,-8.77 -21.62,-20.45 -25.71,-27.47 -3.51,-6.43 5.84,-8.77 15.78,-13.44 9.93,-4.68 19.28,-12.86 24.54,-17.53 4.67,-4.68 4.67,-7.01 8.77,-9.94 3.51,-2.92 11.69,-6.43 15.19,-9.35 4.09,-2.92 4.09,-5.26 11.69,-8.18 8.18,-2.92 23.37,-6.43 30.39,-13.44m360.55,246.63c6.43,-8.18 20.45,-17.53 29.8,-19.87 9.93,-1.75 15.78,4.09 25.71,5.26 9.35,0.58 23.37,-2.92 28.05,3.51 4.67,7.01 1.17,24.55 0,34.48 -1.17,9.35 1.17,11.69 1.75,12.27 1.17,1.17 1.17,1.17 8.77,-1.75 8.18,-2.92 23.37,-8.77 30.39,-1.17 7.01,8.18 4.67,29.22 4.09,40.91 -1.17,11.69 -1.17,14.03 0,14.61 0.58,1.17 2.92,1.17 10.52,4.09 7.6,2.92 21.62,8.77 27.46,17.53 5.84,8.77 3.51,20.45 5.84,29.22 1.75,8.77 7.6,14.61 8.77,24.55 0.58,9.35 -2.92,23.38 -2.92,32.14 0,8.77 3.51,12.27 5.84,20.45 1.75,7.6 1.75,19.29 7.6,26.3 5.84,6.43 17.53,8.77 23.37,17.53 5.84,8.77 5.84,23.96 5.84,32.14 0,7.6 0,7.6 -8.77,5.84 -8.77,-2.34 -26.3,-5.84 -33.89,-1.17 -8.18,4.68 -5.84,18.7 -11.1,28.05 -4.67,9.94 -16.36,15.78 -23.96,14.61 -8.18,-0.58 -11.69,-8.77 -18.7,-14.61 -7.01,-5.84 -16.36,-9.35 -23.37,-9.35 -7.01,0 -10.52,3.51 -17.53,4.68 -7.01,1.17 -16.36,-1.17 -25.13,2.92 -8.77,4.09 -16.95,13.44 -19.87,21.62 -2.92,7.6 -0.58,13.44 -7.6,17.53 -7.01,3.51 -22.21,5.84 -30.97,8.77 -8.77,2.92 -11.1,6.43 -11.69,13.44 -1.17,7.01 -1.17,16.36 -5.26,20.45 -3.51,4.09 -11.69,1.75 -17.53,-5.84 -5.84,-7.6 -9.35,-21.62 -16.36,-28.05 -7.01,-7.01 -16.36,-7.01 -23.37,0.58 -7.01,8.18 -10.52,23.38 -16.36,30.39 -5.84,7.01 -14.02,4.68 -18.7,1.75 -4.67,-2.92 -7.01,-6.43 -12.86,-11.69 -5.84,-4.68 -15.19,-10.52 -18.11,-18.12 -2.92,-8.18 0.58,-17.53 8.77,-24.55 7.6,-7.01 19.28,-10.52 25.13,-12.86 5.84,-1.75 5.84,-1.75 5.84,-2.92 0,-0.58 0,-2.92 1.75,-5.84 2.34,-2.92 5.84,-6.43 8.77,-12.27 2.92,-5.84 5.26,-14.03 -3.51,-22.79 -8.77,-8.77 -28.63,-18.12 -36.23,-28.05 -7.6,-9.94 -4.09,-19.29 -2.92,-24.55 1.17,-4.68 -1.17,-4.68 -1.75,-9.35 -1.17,-5.26 -1.17,-14.61 -7.01,-22.79 -5.84,-7.6 -17.53,-13.44 -25.13,-12.27 -8.18,0.58 -11.69,8.77 -18.7,12.27 -7.01,4.09 -16.36,4.09 -23.37,2.34 -7.01,-2.34 -10.52,-5.84 -17.53,-9.94 -7.01,-4.09 -16.36,-7.6 -23.37,-7.01 -7.01,1.17 -10.52,7.01 -18.7,11.69 -7.6,5.26 -19.28,8.77 -26.88,5.26 -8.18,-4.09 -11.69,-15.78 -12.86,-25.71 -1.17,-9.35 1.17,-17.53 -7.01,-21.04 -7.6,-4.09 -25.13,-4.09 -33.89,-5.26 -8.77,-0.58 -8.77,-2.92 -14.61,-4.68 -5.84,-1.75 -17.53,-4.09 -23.37,-4.68 -5.84,-1.17 -5.84,-1.17 -4.09,-7.01 2.34,-5.84 5.84,-17.53 11.69,-24.55 5.84,-6.43 14.02,-8.77 16.95,-14.61 2.92,-5.84 0.58,-15.2 -7.01,-23.96 -7.6,-8.77 -21.62,-16.95 -26.3,-24.55 -4.67,-7.6 -1.17,-15.78 7.01,-19.29 7.6,-4.09 19.28,-4.09 29.22,-5.84 9.35,-2.34 17.53,-5.84 22.21,-8.18 4.67,-1.75 7.01,-1.75 10.52,5.26 4.09,6.43 9.93,20.45 16.95,28.05 6.43,7.6 14.61,9.94 22.21,2.92 7.6,-7.01 15.78,-22.21 19.28,-30.39 4.09,-7.6 4.09,-7.6 9.93,-6.43 5.84,0.58 17.53,2.92 24.54,9.35 6.43,7.01 8.77,18.7 12.27,25.71 4.09,6.43 9.93,8.77 14.02,9.35 3.51,1.17 5.84,1.17 10.52,0 4.67,-0.58 12.86,-2.92 17.53,-10.52 4.67,-7.6 7.01,-21.62 5.84,-30.39 -1.17,-8.77 -4.67,-12.27 -5.84,-17.53 -1.17,-4.68 1.17,-10.52 4.67,-16.36 4.09,-5.84 9.93,-11.69 15.78,-13.44 5.84,-2.34 11.69,0 16.36,3.51 5.26,4.09 8.77,9.94 15.78,12.86 7.01,2.92 16.36,2.92 23.37,8.77 7.01,5.84 10.52,17.53 17.53,22.21 7.01,5.26 16.36,2.92 24.54,5.26 7.6,1.75 13.44,7.6 22.21,6.43 8.77,-0.58 20.45,-8.77 26.3,-15.2 5.84,-7.01 5.84,-12.86 12.86,-20.45M830.6,606.93c-2.34,8.77 0,14.61 3.51,18.7 4.09,3.51 9.93,5.84 11.69,14.61 2.34,8.77 0,23.96 8.18,30.97 7.6,7.01 25.13,4.68 35.06,5.84 9.35,1.17 11.69,4.68 11.69,11.69 0,7.01 -2.34,16.36 -2.92,22.21 -1.17,5.84 -1.17,8.18 4.67,11.69 5.84,4.09 17.53,9.94 25.13,11.69 8.18,2.34 11.69,0 17.53,-0.58 5.84,-1.17 14.02,-1.17 18.7,-2.92 4.67,-2.34 7.01,-5.84 13.44,-9.94 7.01,-4.09 18.7,-7.6 25.71,-9.94 6.43,-1.75 8.77,-1.75 16.36,-1.75 7.6,0 21.62,0 29.22,4.68 7.6,5.26 9.93,14.61 15.78,21.62 5.84,7.01 15.19,10.52 20.45,13.44 4.67,2.92 4.67,5.26 11.69,9.94 6.43,4.68 20.45,12.86 29.8,15.78 9.93,2.92 15.78,0.58 18.7,9.35 2.92,8.77 2.92,28.64 2.92,39.16 0,10.52 0,12.86 1.17,16.36 0.58,4.09 2.92,9.94 12.27,12.86 9.93,2.92 27.46,2.92 35.06,9.94 8.18,6.43 5.84,20.45 0,26.3 -5.84,5.84 -15.19,3.51 -21.04,9.35 -5.84,5.84 -8.18,19.87 -15.78,28.64 -7.6,8.77 -21.62,12.27 -18.7,22.21 2.92,9.94 22.79,25.13 30.39,35.07 7.6,9.94 4.09,13.44 -7.6,10.52 -11.69,-2.92 -31.56,-12.27 -40.9,-21.04 -9.93,-8.77 -9.93,-16.95 -17.53,-22.79 -8.18,-5.84 -23.37,-9.35 -35.06,-10.52 -11.69,-1.17 -19.87,1.17 -24.54,1.75 -4.67,1.17 -7.01,1.17 -10.52,-2.92 -4.09,-3.51 -9.93,-11.69 -12.86,-17.53 -2.92,-5.84 -2.92,-9.35 -4.67,-14.61 -2.34,-4.68 -5.84,-10.52 -14.61,-12.27 -8.77,-2.34 -22.79,0 -32.14,2.92 -9.93,2.92 -15.78,6.43 -20.45,9.35 -5.26,2.92 -8.77,5.26 -11.1,12.86 -1.75,7.6 -1.75,21.62 -2.92,29.22 -0.58,7.6 -2.92,9.94 -12.27,8.77 -9.93,-1.17 -27.46,-4.68 -37.4,-11.69 -9.35,-7.01 -11.69,-16.36 -9.35,-23.38 1.75,-7.01 7.6,-10.52 7.6,-19.29 0,-8.77 -5.84,-22.79 -9.93,-29.22 -3.51,-7.01 -5.84,-7.01 -8.77,-5.84 -2.92,0.58 -6.43,2.92 -15.19,-1.17 -8.77,-4.09 -22.79,-13.44 -26.3,-23.38 -4.09,-9.94 1.75,-19.29 -2.34,-27.47 -3.51,-7.6 -17.53,-13.44 -23.96,-20.45 -7.01,-6.43 -7.01,-14.61 -11.69,-23.96 -5.26,-9.94 -14.61,-21.62 -18.7,-28.64 -4.09,-6.43 -1.75,-8.77 -1.75,-15.2 0,-7.01 -2.34,-18.7 -2.92,-24.55 -1.17,-5.84 -1.17,-5.84 5.84,-9.94 6.43,-3.51 20.45,-11.69 26.3,-19.29 5.84,-7.6 3.51,-15.78 -1.17,-22.21 -4.67,-7.01 -12.86,-12.86 -16.36,-15.78 -4.09,-2.92 -4.09,-2.92 -8.18,-9.94 -3.51,-6.43 -11.69,-20.45 -20.45,-23.96 -8.77,-4.09 -18.11,1.75 -26.3,0 -7.6,-2.34 -13.44,-11.69 -15.19,-18.7 -2.34,-7.01 0,-10.52 3.51,-15.78 4.09,-4.68 9.93,-10.52 11.69,-19.29 2.34,-8.77 0,-20.45 -2.92,-27.47 -2.92,-6.43 -6.43,-8.77 -11.69,-15.2 -4.67,-7.01 -10.52,-18.7 -9.35,-28.64 0.58,-9.35 8.77,-17.53 8.77,-28.05 0,-10.52 -8.18,-24.55 -8.18,-33.9 0,-9.94 8.18,-15.78 16.95,-11.1 8.77,5.26 18.11,20.45 26.88,25.71 8.77,4.68 16.95,-1.17 24.54,-4.09 7.6,-2.92 15.78,-2.92 21.62,1.75 5.84,5.26 9.35,14.61 3.51,23.38 -5.84,8.77 -21.04,16.95 -29.22,23.38 -7.6,7.01 -7.6,12.86 -0.58,19.87 6.43,6.43 20.45,14.61 26.88,18.12 7.01,4.09 7.01,4.09 12.86,5.26 5.84,0.58 17.53,2.92 26.3,11.69 8.77,8.77 14.61,23.96 16.36,32.73 2.34,8.77 0,11.1 -3.51,17.53 -4.09,7.01 -9.93,18.7 -11.69,27.47m1557.88,92.34c2.34,5.84 5.84,14.03 8.77,18.7 2.92,4.68 5.26,7.01 12.86,0 7.6,-7.01 21.62,-22.21 28.05,-30.39 7.01,-7.6 7.01,-7.6 8.77,-8.77 2.34,-0.58 5.84,-2.92 8.18,-9.35 1.75,-7.01 1.75,-18.7 -4.09,-26.3 -5.84,-8.18 -17.53,-11.69 -26.3,-12.86 -8.77,-1.17 -14.61,1.17 -17.53,1.75 -2.92,1.17 -2.92,1.17 -1.17,5.84 2.34,5.26 5.84,14.61 2.92,23.38 -2.92,8.77 -12.27,16.95 -17.53,22.79 -4.67,5.84 -4.67,9.35 -2.92,15.2m-946.65,135.59c8.18,4.68 17.53,12.86 27.46,15.78 9.93,2.92 19.28,0.58 24.54,7.6 4.67,7.01 4.67,22.21 6.43,30.97 2.34,8.77 5.84,11.1 5.84,20.45 0,9.94 -3.51,27.47 -13.44,32.14 -9.93,5.26 -25.13,-2.92 -35.06,-2.92 -9.93,0 -13.44,8.18 -21.62,11.1 -7.6,2.92 -19.28,0.58 -26.3,-2.34 -6.43,-2.92 -8.77,-6.43 -15.19,-6.43 -7.01,0 -18.7,3.51 -26.3,4.68 -8.18,1.17 -11.69,-1.17 -18.7,2.92 -7.01,4.09 -16.36,13.44 -23.37,15.78 -7.01,1.75 -10.52,-4.09 -9.93,-15.78 1.17,-11.69 7.01,-29.22 8.77,-39.74 2.34,-11.1 0,-14.61 -0.58,-17.53 -1.17,-2.92 -1.17,-5.26 2.92,-9.94 3.51,-4.68 11.69,-12.86 10.52,-24.55 -1.17,-11.69 -10.52,-26.88 -14.61,-35.65 -4.09,-8.77 -1.75,-11.1 7.01,-14.03 8.77,-2.92 23.96,-6.43 32.14,-11.69 7.6,-4.68 7.6,-10.52 14.61,-16.36 6.43,-5.84 20.45,-11.69 29.8,-9.94 9.93,2.34 15.78,11.69 16.95,20.45 0.58,8.77 -2.92,16.95 -11.69,18.7 -8.77,1.75 -22.79,-1.75 -32.14,4.68 -9.93,7.01 -15.78,24.55 -15.78,34.48 0,9.35 5.84,11.69 16.36,7.6 11.1,-4.09 26.3,-13.44 34.48,-19.29 7.6,-5.84 7.6,-8.18 10.52,-8.18 2.92,0 8.77,2.34 16.36,7.01M506.87,1336.3c-3.51,8.18 -11.69,11.69 -21.04,11.1 -9.93,-1.17 -21.62,-7.01 -28.63,-7.01 -6.43,0 -8.77,5.84 -10.52,12.86 -1.75,6.43 -4.09,14.61 -5.84,19.29 -1.75,4.68 -4.09,7.01 -14.61,1.17 -10.52,-5.84 -30.39,-19.87 -40.9,-26.3 -10.52,-7.01 -12.86,-7.01 -15.78,-4.09 -2.92,2.92 -6.43,8.77 -8.77,14.61 -1.75,5.84 -1.75,11.69 -2.92,15.78 -0.58,3.51 -2.92,5.84 -9.35,8.77 -7.01,2.92 -18.7,6.43 -26.3,12.27 -8.18,5.84 -11.69,14.03 -14.02,17.53 -1.75,4.09 -1.75,4.09 -2.92,11.69 -0.58,8.18 -2.92,23.38 2.34,32.14 4.67,8.77 16.36,11.1 17.53,20.45 0.58,9.94 -8.77,27.47 -14.61,37.4 -5.84,9.35 -8.18,11.69 -11.1,12.27 -2.92,1.17 -6.43,1.17 -9.35,2.34 -2.92,0.58 -5.26,2.92 -8.18,3.51 -2.92,1.17 -6.43,1.17 -12.27,-0.58 -5.84,-2.34 -14.02,-5.84 -17.53,-14.03 -4.09,-7.6 -4.09,-19.29 2.92,-28.05 6.43,-8.77 20.45,-14.61 26.88,-17.53 7.01,-2.92 7.01,-2.92 1.17,-9.94 -5.84,-6.43 -17.53,-20.45 -26.3,-25.13 -8.77,-4.68 -14.61,-1.17 -17.53,0 -2.92,1.17 -2.92,-1.17 -4.67,-9.94 -2.34,-8.77 -5.84,-23.96 -14.02,-32.73 -7.6,-8.77 -19.28,-11.1 -26.3,-8.18 -6.43,2.92 -8.77,11.1 -10.52,15.78 -1.75,4.68 -4.09,7.01 -12.86,10.52 -8.77,4.09 -23.96,9.94 -32.72,11.69 -8.77,2.34 -11.1,0 -16.95,-0.58 -5.84,-1.17 -15.19,-1.17 -21.04,-2.34 -5.84,-0.58 -8.18,-2.92 -11.69,-9.35 -4.09,-7.01 -9.93,-18.7 -8.18,-27.47 2.34,-8.77 11.69,-14.61 14.02,-23.38 1.75,-8.77 -4.09,-20.45 -5.84,-27.47 -2.34,-6.43 0,-8.77 6.43,-8.77 7.01,0 18.7,2.34 26.3,8.18 8.18,5.84 11.69,15.2 14.61,20.45 2.92,4.68 5.26,4.68 14.02,8.77 8.77,3.51 23.96,11.69 35.06,7.6 10.52,-4.09 16.36,-19.29 22.21,-28.05 5.84,-8.77 11.69,-11.1 16.36,-18.7 5.26,-7.6 8.77,-21.62 15.78,-26.3 7.01,-4.68 16.36,-1.17 26.3,-7.01 9.93,-5.84 19.28,-21.04 27.46,-29.22 7.6,-7.6 13.44,-7.6 17.53,-7.6 3.51,0 5.84,0 15.19,1.17 9.93,0.58 27.46,2.92 37.4,4.68 9.35,1.75 11.69,4.09 9.35,9.94 -1.75,5.84 -7.6,15.2 -2.92,21.04 5.26,5.84 20.45,8.18 28.63,2.92 7.6,-4.68 7.6,-16.36 8.77,-23.96 0.58,-8.18 2.92,-11.69 9.35,-11.1 7.01,1.17 18.7,7.01 26.3,14.03 8.18,6.43 11.69,14.61 14.02,19.29 1.75,4.68 1.75,7.01 10.52,8.77 8.77,1.75 26.3,4.09 35.06,10.52 8.77,7.01 8.77,18.7 4.67,26.3" android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="m2201.53,1109.24c0,5.26 2.6,8.77 9.11,11.1 6.51,1.75 16.92,1.75 22.78,-1.17 5.21,-2.92 5.21,-8.77 0.65,-14.61 -3.9,-5.84 -13.02,-11.69 -18.22,-13.44 -5.21,-2.34 -7.81,0 -9.76,3.51 -1.95,4.09 -4.56,9.94 -4.56,14.61"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" android:strokeColor="#1f3846"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="0.69999999"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="m574.62,1418.99c-1.95,7.01 -1.95,12.86 -0.65,17.53 0.65,5.26 3.25,8.77 9.76,11.69 6.51,2.92 16.92,5.26 23.43,5.26 6.51,0 9.11,-2.34 12.36,-2.34 3.25,0 7.16,2.34 13.67,2.34 6.51,0 15.62,-2.34 20.82,-2.92 5.21,-1.17 7.81,-1.17 11.06,-7.01 3.25,-5.84 7.16,-17.53 7.16,-25.13 0,-8.18 -3.9,-11.69 -9.76,-14.61 -5.21,-2.92 -11.71,-5.26 -19.52,-5.84 -7.16,-1.17 -16.27,-1.17 -20.17,-1.17 -4.56,0 -4.56,0 -7.81,0 -3.25,0 -9.76,0 -14.97,0 -5.86,0 -9.76,0 -14.32,4.09 -4.56,3.51 -8.46,11.69 -11.06,18.12"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" android:strokeColor="#1f3846"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="0.69999999"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="m938.4,1851.47c-5.86,1.17 -9.76,7.01 -12.36,11.1 -1.95,3.51 -1.95,5.84 1.3,8.77 3.25,2.92 9.76,6.43 14.97,6.43 5.86,0 9.76,-3.51 12.36,-7.6 1.95,-4.09 1.95,-7.6 -1.3,-11.69 -3.25,-4.09 -9.76,-7.6 -14.97,-7.01"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" android:strokeColor="#1f3846"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="0.69999999"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#e75b49" android:pathData="m220.38,874.41c0,-3.87 0,-3.87 1.41,-3.87 1.21,0 4.03,0 7.65,4.73 3.62,4.52 8.45,13.99 13.08,16.79 4.63,2.8 9.46,-0.65 12.08,-2.8 2.62,-2.15 3.42,-3.01 7.04,-1.94 3.62,1.08 10.47,4.09 14.69,4.3 4.43,0.43 6.44,-1.72 10.87,-2.37 4.23,-0.86 11.07,0 15.1,1.29 4.03,1.51 5.23,3.66 6.64,4.73 1.41,1.08 2.62,1.08 4.63,2.15 2.01,1.08 4.83,3.23 7.04,3.87 2.42,0.86 4.43,0 9.46,2.58 5.03,2.58 13.08,8.18 17.11,11.84 4.03,3.66 4.03,4.95 7.04,9.04 3.02,3.87 9.06,10.33 13.49,12.91 4.23,2.37 7.04,1.08 11.67,1.29 4.63,0.43 11.47,2.58 16.1,3.23 4.63,0.86 7.45,0 11.07,1.08 3.62,1.08 8.45,4.09 10.06,8.39 1.61,4.3 0.4,9.9 3.02,15.71 2.62,5.81 9.46,11.41 12.68,14.42 3.42,2.8 3.42,2.8 -1.61,3.44 -5.03,0.86 -15.1,2.15 -20.53,4.73 -5.23,2.58 -6.04,6.03 -5.64,9.04 0.4,2.8 1.61,4.95 3.42,6.46 1.61,1.29 3.62,2.15 7.04,6.67 3.22,4.73 8.05,13.34 10.06,18.08 2.01,4.52 1.21,5.38 1.01,5.6 -0.4,0.43 -0.4,0.43 1.01,4.3 1.21,4.09 4.03,11.84 7.25,15.92 3.42,3.87 7.45,3.87 10.47,7.1 3.02,3.23 5.03,9.68 5.03,13.56 0,4.09 -2.01,5.38 -3.42,9.04 -1.21,3.66 -2.01,9.25 -4.23,12.48 -2.42,3.23 -6.44,4.09 -9.06,7.96 -2.82,3.87 -4.03,11.19 -5.03,15.71 -1.01,4.73 -1.81,6.89 -5.03,6.89 -3.42,0 -9.46,-2.15 -12.48,-6.89 -3.02,-4.52 -3.02,-11.84 -7.45,-14.63 -4.23,-2.8 -13.08,-1.51 -18.11,-1.51 -5.03,0 -6.24,-1.29 -5.03,-4.95 1.41,-3.66 5.43,-9.25 6.44,-13.34 1.01,-3.87 -1.01,-6.03 -5.03,-7.53 -4.03,-1.29 -10.06,-2.15 -13.49,-1.72 -3.22,0.43 -4.03,1.72 -9.06,0.43 -5.03,-1.51 -14.29,-5.81 -18.11,-9.47 -3.62,-3.44 -1.61,-6.46 -2.01,-10.76 -0.2,-4.3 -3.02,-9.9 -3.62,-14.2 -0.6,-4.3 0.6,-7.32 0.4,-10.54 -0.4,-3.23 -2.42,-6.67 -3.42,-10.33 -1.01,-3.66 -1.01,-7.1 -5.43,-7.1 -4.23,0 -13.08,3.44 -17.31,5.38 -4.43,1.72 -4.43,1.72 -4.03,-1.08 0.2,-3.01 1.01,-8.61 -1.41,-12.27 -2.42,-3.66 -7.65,-4.95 -11.07,-7.96 -3.42,-2.8 -4.63,-7.1 -7.04,-9.68 -2.42,-2.37 -5.64,-3.23 -8.45,-3.23 -2.62,0 -4.63,0.86 -7.25,0.86 -2.82,0 -6.04,-0.86 -8.05,-5.38 -2.01,-4.73 -2.82,-13.34 -3.42,-18.08 -0.6,-4.52 -1.41,-5.38 -3.02,-7.75 -1.61,-2.58 -4.43,-6.89 -7.04,-8.61 -2.62,-1.94 -5.43,-1.08 -8.65,-3.23 -3.42,-2.15 -7.45,-7.32 -12.48,-8.39 -5.03,-1.08 -11.07,1.94 -14.49,3.66 -3.22,1.72 -4.03,2.58 -5.23,2.58 -1.41,0 -3.42,-0.86 -6.84,-5.38 -3.22,-4.73 -8.05,-13.34 -11.07,-18.08 -3.02,-4.52 -4.23,-5.38 -4.63,-9.25 -0.4,-3.87 0.4,-11.19 2.42,-15.71 2.01,-4.73 5.23,-6.89 9.06,-4.3 3.62,2.37 7.65,9.68 11.67,10.98 4.03,1.51 8.05,-2.8 10.06,-8.82 2.01,-6.24 2.01,-13.99 2.01,-18.08m429.1,41.32c0.2,4.3 1.01,10.76 0,14.42 -1.01,3.44 -3.82,4.3 -7.04,6.03 -3.42,1.72 -7.45,4.73 -8.45,9.25 -1.01,4.73 1.01,11.19 4.63,13.34 3.82,2.15 9.06,0 12.48,-0.65 3.42,-0.86 4.63,0 5.43,3.87 0.6,3.87 0.6,11.19 3.02,15.49 2.21,4.3 7.04,5.6 9.66,6.67 2.62,1.08 3.42,1.94 7.45,2.15 4.03,0.43 11.27,0.43 16.1,4.3 4.63,4.09 6.64,11.84 10.06,16.57 3.22,4.73 8.05,6.03 12.28,1.72 4.43,-4.3 8.45,-14.2 10.47,-19.37 2.01,-4.95 2.01,-4.95 4.43,-5.6 2.21,-0.86 7.04,-2.15 10.67,-5.38 3.62,-3.23 6.44,-8.39 8.65,-11.19 2.42,-2.8 4.43,-3.66 5.84,-4.73 1.21,-1.08 2.01,-2.37 1.21,-6.67 -0.6,-4.3 -2.62,-11.62 -4.03,-15.06 -1.21,-3.66 -2.01,-3.66 -3.02,-4.09 -1.01,-0.22 -2.21,-1.08 -4.03,-4.95 -1.61,-3.87 -3.62,-11.19 -4.23,-15.06 -0.81,-3.87 0,-4.73 3.22,-4.95 3.42,-0.43 9.46,-0.43 12.88,-3.23 3.22,-3.01 4.03,-8.61 1.21,-11.19 -2.62,-2.58 -8.65,-1.72 -12.68,-3.66 -4.03,-1.72 -6.04,-6.03 -7.45,-8.18 -1.21,-2.15 -2.01,-2.15 -4.63,-0.65 -2.62,1.29 -7.45,4.3 -10.47,8.18 -3.02,3.87 -4.23,9.04 -7.65,8.61 -3.42,-0.43 -8.65,-6.03 -13.48,-7.1 -4.63,-1.08 -8.65,2.37 -13.08,3.87 -4.23,1.51 -9.06,0.65 -11.67,1.08 -2.62,0.43 -3.42,1.72 -7.65,3.23 -4.43,1.51 -12.48,2.8 -16.5,4.73 -4.03,1.72 -4.03,3.87 -3.62,8.18m-80.51,66.71c0.2,3.66 -1.01,4.95 -1.41,11.19 -0.4,6.03 0.4,16.79 1.41,22.81 1.01,6.24 2.21,7.53 3.02,8.39 0.6,0.65 0.6,0.65 3.62,-4.09 3.02,-4.52 9.06,-13.99 13.48,-17.43 4.23,-3.66 7.04,-1.51 11.07,-1.51 4.03,0 9.26,-2.15 12.28,-3.66 3.02,-1.29 3.82,-2.15 8.05,-4.52 4.43,-2.58 12.48,-6.89 15.5,-11.19 3.02,-4.3 1.01,-8.61 -3.02,-11.19 -4.03,-2.37 -10.06,-3.23 -14.09,-5.6 -4.03,-2.58 -6.04,-6.89 -10.47,-6.24 -4.23,0.86 -11.07,6.46 -15.1,7.32 -4.03,0.65 -5.23,-3.66 -9.66,-4.3 -4.43,-0.86 -11.67,2.15 -14.49,6.46 -2.62,4.3 -0.6,9.9 -0.2,13.56m-36.63,43.68c0,-5.6 -2.01,-8.61 -6.44,-4.95 -4.23,3.66 -11.07,13.56 -14.29,18.72 -3.42,4.95 -3.42,4.95 -4.83,5.6 -1.21,0.86 -4.03,2.15 -7.25,4.09 -3.42,1.72 -7.45,3.87 -9.46,9.25 -2.01,5.38 -2.01,13.99 -1.61,18.29 0.2,4.3 1.01,4.3 4.63,4.73 3.62,0.22 10.47,1.08 13.69,1.08 3.42,0 3.42,-0.86 5.84,-1.51 2.21,-0.65 7.04,-1.51 10.06,-2.8 3.02,-1.51 4.23,-3.66 4.23,-7.96 0,-4.3 -1.21,-10.76 -1.21,-14.63 0,-4.09 1.21,-5.38 3.02,-10.54 1.61,-4.95 3.62,-13.56 3.62,-19.37"/>
</vector>
```

Screen grab showing issue:
[image]

Answer (score -4):

For that, You have to create and Use 9-Patch images, Please check below link that may help you

> https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch
>
> https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files

Comment: Those appear to be for bitmaps/pngs. This is a vector.